# draw a black/white Bitmap with a medianfilter

Tags: java, bitmap, paint

my task is it to laod a black/white Bitmap in an Boolean [][] array. every bit has some special informations. For now i got the bitmap load. But know i struggel with the drawing ob the Bitmap and the medianfilter .

Here is my Bitmap class. For checking if the Bitmap is correctly loaded i implements a simple print.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bitmap {
  String quelle;
  static int width;
  static int height;
  int pictureStart;
  int b;
  static boolean[][] pixels;
  
  Bitmap(){
//    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//    System.out.println("Bitte den Pfad des Bildes eingeben");
//    this.quelle = sc.nextLine();
    quelle = "D:\\Jade-HS_Oldenburg\\Praktische Informatik1\\workspace\\workspace\\Info3_schmidt\\Bilder\\rose_von_sharon.bmp";
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.pictureStart = 0;
    try(DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(quelle));){
      ds.skipBytes(10);
      
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pictureStart += ds.readUnsignedByte() * (int) Math.pow(256, i);
      }
      
      ds.skipBytes(4);
      
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        width += ds.readUnsignedByte() * (int) Math.pow(256, i);
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        height += ds.readUnsignedByte() * (int) Math.pow(256, i);
      } 
      
      System.out.println("Bildbeginn bei: " + pictureStart);
      System.out.println("Bildbreite: " + width);
      System.out.println("Bildhöhe: " + height);
      
      ds.skipBytes(36);
      
      pixels = new boolean [height][width+3];
      
      for(int i = height-1; i > -1; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1112; j += 8) {
          b = ds.readUnsignedByte();
          if(b / 128 == 1)
            pixels[i][j] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j] = false;
          b %= 128;
          if(b / 64 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+1] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+1] = false;
          b %= 64;
          if(b / 32 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+2] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+2] = false;
          b %= 32;
          if(b / 16 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+3] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+3] = false;
          b %= 16;
          if(b / 8 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+4] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+4] = false;
          b %= 8;
          if(b / 4 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+5] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+5] = false;
          b %= 4;
          if(b / 2 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+6] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+6] = false;
          b %= 2;
          if(b / 1 == 1)
            pixels[i][j+7] = true;
          else
            pixels[i][j+7] = false;
        }
        ds.skipBytes(1);
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fn) {
      System.out.println("Datei nicht gefunden");
    }
    catch(IOException io) {
      System.out.println("Fehler");
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if(pixels[i][j])
          System.out.print("x");
        else
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
//    print();
    View newview =new View();
  
  }
  
  

  
// public void print() {
//   for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
//     for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
//       if(pixels[i][j])
//         System.out.print("x");
//       else
//         System.out.print(" ");
//     }
//     System.out.println();
//   }
// }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bitmap test = new Bitmap();
    
   
  }

}
```

and here ist my View

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View {
  private JFrame frame;
  private JLabel label;
  private  int viewwidth;
  private  int viewheight;
  public static void main(String[] args) {

}
  
  
  /**
   * Create the application.
   * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
   */
  public View() {
    initialize();
  }
  private void initialize() {
    
    frame =new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setToolTipText("");
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
    
    viewwidth= frame.getSize().width /Bitmap.width;
    viewheight=frame.getSize().height / Bitmap.width;

    JPanel pic_new = new JPanel();

    panel.add(pic_new);
    
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
//        int pixelSize = old_pic.size(); // Größe jedes Rechtecks, kann angepasst werden
        for (int i = 0; i < viewwidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < viewheight; j++) {
                int c = Bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
                if (Bitmap.pixels[i][j]) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillRect(x,y,viewwidth,viewheight);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                g.fillRect(x, y, viewheight, viewwidth);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I tried something with the paint() methode, but i think i dont understand it correctly.

for now i need to paint my Bitmap as like i did in the print out and the i need some Tricks for teh medianfilter.

for example:

In bytes 10 to 13 (first byte = 0), the actual start of the image is stored as a 4-byte number.
In bytes 18 to 21, the image width is stored as a 4-byte number.
In bytes 22 to 25, the image height is stored as a 4-byte number.

All 4-byte numbers are stored with the smallest byte first.

Starting from the image beginning, the actual image data is stored:

The bottom row comes first, and the top row comes last.
Each row's 8 pixels are represented by the 8 bits of a byte (1 = white, 0 = black).
If the number of pixels is not divisible by 8, the last byte is filled with zeros on the right.
By padding with 0 to 3 null bytes, each row consists of a number of bytes divisible by 4.
All rows of the image are stored consecutively in this manner.

my medianfilter should be a 3x3 Filter

and i should use <<, >> & and |  for Image processing at the bit level